# Convergence or divergence of $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x} \, dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, improper-integrals

As specified in the title, I desire to determine if the integral
$$ \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x} \, dx $$
either converges or diverges. If it diverges, I would also like to be able to say where to (if the limit goes to $+\infty, -\infty$ or if it simply doesn't exist.

**My attempt.** This is an integral over an infinite interval that also contains a discontinuous integrand. To do this integral we’ll need to split it up into two integrals so each integral contains only one point of discontinuity. With this in mind, we do the following split:

$$ \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \, dx + \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x} \, dx $$

In order for the integral above to be convergent we will need BOTH of these to be convergent. If one or both are divergent then the whole integral will also be divergent. Let us compute, for example, the second integral on the RHS:

$$ \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \lim_{t \to +\infty} \int_1^t \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \lim_{t \to +\infty} \ln(x)\Big|_1^t = \lim_{t \to +\infty} \ln(t) = +\infty. $$
With this, it is confirmed that the integral of interest is divergent.

My doubt comes now: How can I find where it diverges to?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Your attempt is correct. There is a thing to point out, however: the integral is improper in $0$ because the integrand is unbounded in a right neighborhood of $0$. It has nothing to do with continuity. You could redefine $1/x$ to be $75$ in $x=0$ and still have an improper integral. Since it is divergent and the integrand is positive in $(0,\infty)$, it follows that the integral diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Calculating the other integral in a similar way will also give you $+\infty$, so clearly the divergence is to $+\infty$.

Comment: @Bernkastel Thanks for your comments about the continuity part. As for the rest: since the integrand is positive, by the positivity of the Riemann integral, the integral must be positive aswell. This means that the only chance for divergence is $+\infty?$

Comment: _“find where it diverges to?”_ Usually divergent series “don't go anywhere”. Sometimes, as in the case you examined, we'll say that the integral has the value $+\infty$. In other cases, such as $\int_0^{+\infty} \sin t\, dt$ (which oscillates infinitely many times between $-1$ and $1$), the question has no sense at all.

Comment: Hint: you can prove $\int_0^\infty\frac1xdx=\infty$ by comparison with $\int_{1/N}^N\frac1xdx=2\ln N$ for $N>1$.